# How to make the RubberBandXyZoomModifier fill with transparent color SciChart WPF

Tags: scichart

Using SciChart RubberBandXyZoomModifier, how can I make it fill the selection area box with a transparent grey color?

Answer (score 0):

According to the SciChart docs, there are three ways to change the selection area box color for the [RubberBandXyZoomModifier](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/RubberBandXyZoomModifier.html).

1/ Set the RubberBandXyZoomModifier.RubberBandFill, RubberBandStroke properties

```
  <s:RubberBandXyZoomModifier RubberBandFill="#33FFFFFF" RubberBandStroke="#FF3333"/>
```

2/ Set the above properties in a custom theme

see [Creating a Custom Theme](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/Creating%20a%20Custom%20Theme.html)

3/ overring a color of the above properties in an existing theme

see [Overriding colors of our themes](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/Overriding%20Colors%20of%20our%20Themes.html)

Any of the above will achieve the desired result.